# Cross platform web crawling engine

Tags: web-crawler, cross-platform

I need to develop a module that uses a web crawling engine and can run on virtually any device - iOS, android, Windows, etc.

I need a fully automated non visual web engine that can programmatically load pages, execute JS (if desired), manipulate and submit forms, maintain cookies, etc.

What's my best bet in terms of programming framework and the engine itself?

Is there such a license permissive web engine that can efficiently run on any device?

I'd prefer to do the development in visual studio but that is definitely not a must.